# How to design architecture to read a huge database table being updated simultaneously

Tags: database-design, architecture

I am looking for better solutions than mine for a specific architecture design.

Right now, we have one huge user table on our Oracle (about 30 million rows and growing) that is being updated by an existing service which add/removes rows every day, around 10k rows per day only.

We should create a new service that will need to fetch ALL users, do some statistics over it and print a report. I cannot do this report in the database as some extra information will come from other microservices.

Of course the query is taking so long to return and also we need to make it in batches as our new service will not be able to handle it all in the memory.

So I was thinking on creating a in-memory cache (Redis or whatever) for that table, using a Read-Through strategy, the read time will be decreased but then I am afraid that eventually this database will grow and we will run out of memory in a couple months.

Another idea, we could try to scale our Oracle to increase the read instances, and then multi-thread lots of queries with specific ranges.

What other options do I have in this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell us more about the sizing?
As you know you can deploy Redis (and other solutions) multiple shards allowing you to scale, and if you need you can also use Redis On Flash to store some of the values to disk and kee your database very fast.

Comment: on my query, I only need to bring the useful columns, which has less than 500 bytes of data each row. the only problem is our db is growing everyday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Redis would be a good option to provide a quick access to the data.

I do not understand why you are saying that, without mentioning any size for your dataset:

> I am afraid that eventually this database will grow and we will run out of memory in a couple months.

You can deploy a cluster of Redis that will distribute the data on many nodes if eventually, you need more RAM.

You have multiple options to capture updates from Oracle tables:

1. Oracle Change Data Capture
2. Using JDBC Database Change Notification (DCN)

You will receive events with the information that have changed, and you will be able to create/update the key in Redis or any cache using this appraoch.

Comment: Thanks, the dataset is not big, around 500 bytes per row, considering I will only fetch the useful columns, how can I measure the RAM used in Redis?

Comment: Just checked about Change Data Capture, if I make the database notify Redis about changes, then that would be the Write Around caching design?